# Missing part on '87 Ninja 600R

Tags: motorcycle, part-identification, kawasaki, ninja

I bought an '87 Ninja 600R (ZX600b) and can't figure out whats missing that goes in or over this hole.

Is it missing a plug, a hose, or something else?

Is it important?

[image]

Comment: ty i couldn;t seem to find it ..... it did not have an air box when i bought the bike as the previous owner put a vance&hines exhaust and the k&n pod filters on it and removed the air box completely....... is it safe to run just open like that? or should I put somesort of hose on it?

Comment: It's odd that there is not more oil everywhere.  When I've removed air boxes in the past I've built a mini PCV system to catch the oil.  One time, I even used a hose and beer can zip tied into the bike because I was broke.  Years and years ago.  Back to the point, yes, you should have something to catch the oil.  Again, what is odd to me, there isn't oil everywhere.  Is your oil level really low on your bike?

Comment: not really low..... a little low but i bought the bike as a non running project for 200 bucks..... couple hours later i got it up and running but found i had a leaking float bowl on 1 of my carbs that i just ordered new gaskets for... i discovered this when i took the tank and carbs off to work on the carbs and it bugged me lol. the bike has been running maybe 20 minutes tops by this point as like i said the carb bowl was leaking and i didn't run it any longer. i did a little investigating after you informed me what it was and looked into oil catch cans and systems

Comment: and not sure if i NEED to run the exhaust port of the catch can back into the intake manifold somehow or if i can just do a filter on the exhaust side as long as i have a catch can on there for the oil.

Comment: You don't NEED to run it back into the intake, although by design it works that way.  You could ebay a stock airbox.   I wouldn't run individual filters on it.  The airbox acts as a resonance chamber and helps with intake efficiency.  If not, run a hose from the connection point to a can and empty out frequently.  Also, check your oil a lot.   The top of your valve cover has reed valves on it for regulating pressure changes as well and that's part of the system.  I would put the stock airbox back in it.  If not, I would jet the bike for the individual filters.

Comment: bike has already been rejetted for the k&n pod filters and the vance&hines exhaust. so at this point just a hose with a catch can should be fine?

Comment: Yup, you should be good.

Comment: apologies for all the questions and i appreciate the responses and your help..... i am assuming it still needs a filter or ability to breathe though as it is a ventilation system of sorts.... so would something work with just an intake a catch can and a air filter? or does it matter on it breathing as in just needs a intake into a closed can. or could i do a can with an intake and output left open or a hose routing out the back.

Comment: http://www.summitracing.com/parts/mor-85402?seid=srese1&gclid=CjwKEAjwjca5BRCAyaPGi6_h8m8SJADryPLhMcMGnb6pjXe-kKMYnuCqda-2ySdbhEPUsCuWA_7QFxoCmd7w_wcB

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39605/discussion-between-ducatikiller-and-ike-ayers).

Answer (score 7):

**There is a hose that connects your air box to this**

As stated in comments, this is connection point for a PCV hose.  The hose connects to the bottom of your air box that attaches to your carburetors.

This hole allows for crankcase ventilation.  Any gasses that should not be released into the atmosphere can be vented here.  It should get pulled back into your motor and burnt, which is why it's connected to you air box.

There are additional emissions related components that are related to this ventilation system including a vacuum diaphragm.

[Link to parts diagram.](https://www.kawasaki.com/Parts/PartsDiagram/139859/1987/ZX600-A3)

See part number 90259D (Breather)

**EDIT**

I think the hose is attached to the bottom of the air box you removed to get that photo.  The connection point is very clean and the cases aren't covered in fresh oil.  Just old stuff.  Look on your air box and I think you may discover the hose that attaches to crank vent is attached to the air box and that you aren't missing any parts after all.

Comment: it did not have an air box when i bought the bike as the previous owner put a vance&hines exhaust and the k&n pod filters on it and removed the air box completely....... is it safe to run just open like that? or should I put somesort of hose on it?

Answer (score 1):

The Breather fitting is missing according to the diagram, [you can buy one on Bike bandit.](http://www.bikebandit.com/oem-parts/1987-kawasaki-ninja-600r-zx600a-ca/o/m150351#sch55436)

Original OEM Part number was 92005-1129

Also it looks like 92005-1017 may be a tube that attaches to  it, but not sure, schematics are not that good. You could call BikeBandit on the phone to figure out what is missing.

[image]

Comment: That part number is the actual fitting that we see in the photograph above.  It's not the correct part.  The correct part is the tube that connects the fitting to the air box.  This is just the fitting you tab into the case for the hose to connect to.